# Creating Arrays in C++

Tags: c++, arrays

Hi i'm new to learning C++ and i just have a quick question.

if i am creating an array containing 5 structs should i clear the array as shown below upon construction or leave it as when i declare it.

in other words is doing something like

```
person a[5];

for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    a[i].name= "";
    a[i].value= 0; 
}
```

the same as doing something like this, please do note that i will basically looping through these later and setting these values.

```
person[5];
```

Comment: `person[5]` is 6th position FYI

Comment: It really depends on the details of the struct itself. And what you want to achieve, of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only POD types that have static storage duration are being zero-initialized upon creation. But since using of uninitialized variables produces **undefined behavior**, it is considered a good practice to initialize variables explicitly, even when it might be redundant.

But instead of initializing it in a loop, it's better to define a default constructor, which will initialize the data members of the instance of `person` when it is constructed:

```
struct person
{
    person() : value(0) { }

    std::string name;
    int value;
}
```

And also note that using of STL containers such as `std::vector` is much better idea than using
C-style arrays :)

Comment: "Your struct is a POD type"  - no it's not, not with `std::string` inside ayway. And you don't need to initialize string with empty "", it has default constructor which does that

Comment: You can't say it is POD without knowing what the types of its members are.

Comment: @juanchopanza, aleguna: Edited.

Answer (score 3):

No, you don't. What you need is a proper default constructor for `person`

Comment: Of course, that has the consequence of rendering `person` a non-aggregate. That could not be an issue, but it is worth mentioning. Also, depending on types of the data members, a user defined default constructor might not be necessary.

Answer (score 3):

Just write a default constructor for `person`, assuming it's a `struct` or `class`.
It will be called to initialize each array element automatically.

In general, you should probably prefer to use `std::vector<person>` instead, but you haven't given enough context to say for sure.

---

The default constructor would look something like: this (note that `std::string` has its own default constructor, so we don't need to do anything for that)

```
struct person {
    std::string name;
    int value;

    person() : value(0) {}
};
```

Now this:

```
person a[5];
```

is properly initialized with no further effort.

---

If you're planning to initialize the elements "properly" later anyway, then using a vector makes it easier to skip the wasted dummy initialization:

```
struct person {
    std::string name;
    int value;

    person() : value(0) {}
    person(std::string const &n, int v) : name(n), value(v) {}
};

std::vector<person> people;
people.reserve(5);
// just create each person with the right values in the first place:
for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
    people.push_back(person(get_name(i), get_value(i)));
}
```

---

Finally, if you don't mind having uninitialized memory around, your first version (with no constructor and no loop) is fine. However, note that losing track of which elements/members are valid and which are garbage, is a fertile source of bugs.

Answer (score 2):

Is there any reasons why you can not use a [vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/)? It is they C++ way and it will be much easier and less likely to have bugs that way. Here is an example:

```
 #include <vector>

 std::vector<person> a ;

 a.push_back( person(...) ) ;
```

Also, as mentioned if you need to use arrays then having a default constructor for `person` assure that you do not need to initialize later on. For example:

```
class person
{
   public:
     person() : value(0) {...} // default constructor
};
```

Comment: Maybe they want a fixed size, aggregate structure.

Comment: @juanchopanza I amended to mention default ctor if they needed to use arrays

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned above person[5] is the 6th position

In C++ dont use array and instead use vectors

Answer (score 0):

On the first line, where you declare your array, the default `person` constructor will be invoked 5 times (once per element of your array). If your `person` constructor initializes the `name` and `value` elements to sensible values, there is no need for your loop.

Answer (score 0):

No, they are not the same.

In the first example:

```
person a[5];
```

You are declaring an array of length 5, of type person.

However, this:

```
person[5]
```

This is not valid - there is no variable name, nothing to be assigned, nothing that you can loop through later.